# when adding a new row on ngx datatable scroll down latest row

Tags: angularjs, ngx-datatable

Hi I am using Angularjs2 and ngx-datatable to populate some data. And I have a button to add new row to the bottom of the datatable like this.

```
<a *ngIf="isView" mdTooltip="Add City" style="padding-left:25px;" (click)="addCities()" md-icon role="img" class="material-icons"
  aria-label="mode edit" id="editObs">add_circle</a>
```

And this is the angular function to insert a new row.

```
addCities() {    
let deviceObv = {
  Id: (this.cities.length > 0) ? parseInt(this.cities[this.cities.length - 1]["Id"]) + 1 : 1,
  Name: "",
  Description: "",
}
this.cities.push(deviceObv);
this.editing[(this.cities.length - 1) + '-cell'] = true
}
```

And this is the ngx-datatable definition.

```
<ngx-datatable class='material' [columns]="columns" [columnMode]="'force'" [headerHeight]="40" [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="'auto'"
  [rows]='cities' [scrollbarH]="true">
```

what i need is to scroll to the latest row when adding a new row?

Any idea?